# What is better approach of doing this PHP + MYSQL in one page?

Tags: php, html, coding-style

My approach:

```
<?

switch($id) 
{ 
    case 1:
?>
        a lots of html stuff goes here...
<?    
    break;  
    case 2:
?>
        a lots of html stuff goes here2...
<?    
    break;        
}

?>
```

Is there any way to do this thing *prettier?* I mean more readable or something? I would really appreaciate that. (haven't learned smarty yet...)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Break out the HTML into separate files and include them in the relevant blocks.

Comment: Yeah, probably that's the best solution here.

Answer (score 1):

include as has been mentioned. Or if you really want to separate it out you could use a template engine such as [Smarty](http://smarty.net)

Comment: Smarty won't help in this very case. And such a separation should be done in *mind*, not code. Smarty has {PHP} tag as well....

Answer (score 0):

`if` statements might be cleaner here:

```
<? 
if ($id == 1) {  
?> 
        a lots of html stuff goes here... 
<?     
}
if ($id == 2) {
?> 
        a lots of html stuff goes here2... 
<?     
} 
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend a full templating solution like Smarty (which Cfreak has mentioned already), it is a good idea to separate presentation from logic.

Comment: I realize that, however I find the code ugly, and it allows for more of a separation between presentation and logic.